# Rails joins through association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, join, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In Ruby on Rails, I want to find employers in the city.
Lets say the models are set up this way:

```
City
has_many :suburbs
has_many :households, :through => suburbs
has_many :people, :through => suburbs

Suburb
has_many :households
has_many people, :through => households
belongs_to :city


Household
has_many :people
belongs_to :suburb

People
belongs_to :household
belongs_to :employer


Employer
has_many :people
```

I feel like I want some sort of Employer joins some_city.people but I don't know how to do this. If people belonged directly to cities, I could join Employer to people where city_id is something, but I want to find the same data without that direct join and I am a little lost.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in rails?  Why not just use their helper methods?

Comment: I am sorry, which helper method would you recommend for this?

Comment: Why don't you traverse the relationships via `has_many :through` from `Employer` like you're doing from `City`?

Comment: Nvm, not sure what the best way to do this would be, sry

Comment: An employer could be multi-city, so it would not necessarily belong to a city exclusively. I could create a join table, but that seems like a lot to do for this.  I could give people a city_id, but that does not seem like the normalized way to do this because that information should be available though the current records.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do the join like jvans has illustrated.  Or you can setup your relationships like the following:

```
class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people
  has_many :households, through: :people
  has_many :suburbs, through: :households
  has_many :cities, through: :suburbs
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :household
  belongs_to :employer
end


class Household < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :suburb
  has_many :people
end

class Suburb < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  has_many :households
  has_many :people, through: :households
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :suburbs
  has_many :households, through: :suburbs
  has_many :people, through: :households
  has_many :employers, through: :people
end
```

Then you can join `City` from `Employer`, and vice-versa, directly.

For example:

```
Employer.joins(:cities).where("cities.name = ?", "Houston").first

SELECT "employers".* FROM "employers" 
INNER JOIN "people" ON "people"."employer_id" = "employers"."id" 
INNER JOIN "households" ON "households"."id" = "people"."household_id" 
INNER JOIN "suburbs" ON "suburbs"."id" = "households"."suburb_id" 
INNER JOIN "cities" ON "cities"."id" = "suburbs"."city_id" WHERE (cities.name = 'Houston') 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Wow. I was totally unaware I could make that kind of association. Let me go implement this, I suspect this is precisely the answer I am looking for for working out future similar queries and stuff.

Comment: Yeah, as of Rails 3.1, the nested `has_many :through` relationships work quite well.

Answer (score 51):

Use nested joins

```
Employer.joins({:people => {:household => {:suburb => :city}}})
```

should give you the join table you're looking. If you were traversing the other direction you would use plural names

```
City.joins( :suburbs => {:households => {:people => :employers }})
```

Comment: Okay I think this is what I was asking about. Just to clear up the syntax, how would that final association be made to identify a particular city? Say I want to find all the employers who employ people of Chicago, which has a model ID of 1?

Comment: Add a where clause to it .where("employers.city IN ? AND employers.id  in ?, city, id)

Comment: Also fwiw I'm rewriting a gem called searchlogic to work with active record 3 and should be done soon. It makes doing searches like this in your app pretty trivial.  https://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic?source=cr

Comment: Thanks for the help. I chose the other answer but learned a lot from all of the responses. I will keep an eye out for searchlogic, great work.

Comment: @jvans - thank you - what if you want an employer given you have a city e.g. say 'Houston'?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon add a where clause. 

`Employer.joins({:people => {:household => {:suburb => :city}}}) .where("cities.name = 'Houston'")`